# Create a action link inside a ASP.NET MVC 3 form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, actionlink

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AbuseReportInfo", "Admin",  new {id = @Model.Id, verify = true }))
{
    <div class="cashOutHistory-item-header">
         @Html.ActionLink(@Model.Material.Name, "Details", "Material", new { id = Model.Material.Id }, null)
    </div>
    <div class="cashOutHistory-item-header">
        Subject:
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="cashOutHistory-item">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject)
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="cashOutHistory-item-header">
        Description</div>
    <div>
        <span class="cashOutHistory-item">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </span>
    </div>
    <p> 
        <input type="submit" id="btnVerify" name="btnVerify" value="Discard" />
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

When creating the action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Model.Material.Name, "Details", "Material", new { id = Model.Material.Id }, null)
```

the link is not clickable when the page is loaded.

But when placing the action link below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

the link is working.

Why is this? I want the link to be able to work where its originally placed.

Comment: What HTML is generated in your first example?

Comment: Some javascript is attached through some selector is canceling redirect event?

Answer (score 0):

as @Giredrius mentioned in the comments, there is a fair chance that some javascript code is cancelling out the click event try changing the id or name for testing like e.g.

```
@Html.ActionLink("test name", "Details", "Material", new { id = "TestId_1"}, null)
```

if the above code works that will confirm the presence of cancelling js code, then search your js files for that code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the second `@` sign in this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Model.Material.Name, "Details", "Material", new { id = Model.Material.Id }, null)
```

Change it to:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Material.Name, "Details", "Material", new { id = Model.Material.Id }, null)
```

You are already in the Razor parser with the `@Html`, so the second marker may be throwing off the parser.